# Conflict between unicode-math and glossaries-extra

Tags: xetex, glossaries, unicode-math

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[symbols]{glossaries-extra}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\makeglossaries
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={tilde}]{tilde}{\ensuremath{\tilde{D}}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={hat}]{hat}{\ensuremath{\hat{D}}}

\begin{document}
\printglossary[type=symbols, style=long]
\begin{itemize}
    \item gls: $\gls{tilde}$, $\gls{hat}$
    \item ensuremath: $\ensuremath{\tilde{D}}$, $\ensuremath{\hat{D}}$
    \item normal: $\tilde{D}$, $\hat{D}$
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

The output looks like this.

[image]

How should I fix this shifted tilde?

Answer (score 3):

**`unicode-math` side**:

`\setmathfont` redefines `\tilde`, this changes the one-step expansion of `\tilde` from `\protect\tilde␣` to `\tilde`. And if `\setmathfont` is not used in preamble, `unicode-math` uses it at the beginning of `document` environment.

**`glossaries-extra` side**:

The first usage of `\gls{tilde}` uses the value of an internal macro corresponding to the `glossaries` option `first`. If not used, `first` inherits the value of option `text`, and the latter one inherits the value of option `name`. And your example is equivalent to setting `name={\ensuremath{\tilde{D}}}`.

By default, the options `first` and `text` store their value by an protected expansion (using `\protected@xdef`). Hence the corresponding internal macros both store `\protect\ensuremath␣{\protect\tilde␣{D}}`.

**Combine both**:

In OP's example,

- In `\glsxtrnewsymbol`, one-step expansion of `\tilde`, which is `\protect\tilde␣`, is stored for `\gls` to use.
- At the beginning of document, `\setmathfont` redefines `\tilde`, but not `\tilde␣`.
- Hence `\gls{tilde}` is more or less equivalent to `\ensuremath{\tilde␣{D}}`, which produces wrong position of math accent tilde.

**Workaround**:

In general, protecting `\tilde` from one-step expansion, or switching off the expansion of options `first` and `text` both fix the problem.

```
% solution 1, protect \tilde
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={tilde}]{tilde}{\ensuremath{\protect\tilde{D}}}

% solution 2, switch off the expansion of options `first` and `text`
\glssetnoexpandfield{text}
\glssetnoexpandfield{first}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={tilde}]{tilde}{\ensuremath{\tilde{D}}}
```

In particular, explicitly use the `\setmathfont` before defining any glossary entries also works. This is why @cicada's answer works.

This [answer on zhihu.com](https://www.zhihu.com/question/375598575/answer/1047360421), posted by myself but in Chinese, to the almost same question provides more details and uses a different way of explanation. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Loading `unicode-math` package before `glossaries-extra`, and setting a math font for `unicode-math` to use seems to do the trick:

[image: tilde D]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage[symbols,automake]{glossaries-extra}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}

\makeglossaries
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={tilde}]{tilde}{\ensuremath{\tilde{D}}}
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={hat}]{hat}{\ensuremath{\hat{D}}}

\begin{document}
\printglossary[type=symbols, style=long]
\begin{itemize}
    \item gls: $\gls{tilde}$, $\gls{hat}$
    \item ensuremath: $\ensuremath{\tilde{D}}$, $\ensuremath{\hat{D}}$
    \item normal: $\tilde{D}$, $\hat{D}$
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```